# Creating css3 infinite rotation for all major browsers

Tags: javascript, gwt, animation, css, rotation

I created an infinite rotation animation using GWT (javascript) and CSS3 properties: I created a timer that repeatedly sets the "transform" property to "rotate(currentVal + 360)" (for webkit, opera, firefox, safari). 
The problem is that this method uses about 10-15% CPU (on chrome) nad 20-25% CPU on firefox (Intel Core2 Duo 1.8 GHz) and I don't understand why. 
Is there an alternate solution ?(for all major browsers, not just chrome or safari let's say...) or is something I may be doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have a look at [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) which uses SVG. This is less cpu-consuming...

Comment: Cool! I found this for GWT http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/. Would you recommend it ? :)

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. If you only want to rotate an image, you might not need the whole raphaeljs-library. In this case you should check out the specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/ Example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Soccer_ball_animated.svg

Comment: There is also a jQuery-Plugin providing a rotation functionality: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: Sorry, I mixed commends with answers... see below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now CSS3 is not hardware accelerated yet, at least not with the browsers you tested.
But there are several other possibilities to rotate an image besides CSS3:

- [Raphaël-JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)
- [jQueryRotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) (a jQuery-Plugin)

Those libraries work with SVG which is IMHO less cpu-consuming.
If you only want to rotate an image, you might not need the whole raphaeljs-library. In this case you should check out the specs: w3.org/TR/SVG11

Live example:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Soccer_ball_animated.svg

Comment: I didn't use SVG animation because there is a bug on chrome/chromium where certain elements' animation is not triggered (in some weird situations - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771335/svg-animation-not-working-in-chrome-using-animatetransform-in-gwt). I believed they fixed it: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13585